# Polars - Flatten rows into columns, aggregating by column values

Tags: python, dataframe, etl, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm trying to write a script in Polars that would flatten a list of prices per date and minute. The catch is I want to incrementally aggregate into columns and zero out values in the future. For example. Idea is to make this solution vectorized if possible to make it performant.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02", 
             "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-03"],
    "minute": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "price": [10, 20, 15, 10, 20, 30, 60, 70]
})
```

Should build the following dataframe.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| date         | minute | 1_price | 2_price | 3_price  
-------------------------------------------------------
| "2022-01-01" | 1      | 10      | 0       | 0
| "2022-01-01" | 2      | 10      | 20      | 0
| "2022-01-02" | 1      | 15      | 0       | 0
| "2022-01-02" | 2      | 15      | 10      | 0
| "2022-01-02" | 3      | 15      | 10      | 20
| "2022-01-03" | 1      | 30      | 0       | 0
| "2022-01-03" | 2      | 30      | 60      | 0
| "2022-01-03" | 3      | 30      | 60      | 70
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
df.join(
    df.pivot('price', 'date','minute','first'),
    on='date') \
    .select("date", "minute",
            **{f"{x}_price":pl.when(pl.lit(x)<=pl.col('minute'))
                              .then(pl.col(f"{x}"))
                              .otherwise(0)
                              for x in df['minute'].unique().sort()})
shape: (8, 5)
┌────────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ minute ┆ 1_price ┆ 2_price ┆ 3_price │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞════════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1      ┆ 10      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1      ┆ 15      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2      ┆ 15      ┆ 10      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3      ┆ 15      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1      ┆ 30      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2      ┆ 30      ┆ 60      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3      ┆ 30      ┆ 60      ┆ 70      │
└────────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

What your example shows is more than just flattening but it seems what you're looking for is that the x_price column should be 0 whenever the x is greater than whatever is in the minute column. That's what this does through a pivot, self join, and when/then/otherwise.

Comment: I think pivot works fine when I have only price column. But lets say I have 3 columns that requires the same treatment. price, open, close.

Comment: It's mostly the same but in pivot you give it `['price','open']` instead of just `'price'` and then the column naming is different so you have to work through that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`cumulative_eval`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html#polars-expr-cumulative-eval) with [`element.implode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.implode.html#polars.Expr.implode), [`list.to_struct()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.to_struct.html) and [`unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) to achieve the result:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("price")
      .cumulative_eval(pl.element().implode())
      .over("date")
      .list.to_struct(n_field_strategy="max_width", fields = lambda x: f"{x+1}_price")
).unnest("price").fill_null(0)

┌────────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ minute ┆ 1_price ┆ 2_price ┆ 3_price │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞════════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1      ┆ 10      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1      ┆ 15      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2      ┆ 15      ┆ 10      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3      ┆ 15      ┆ 10      ┆ 20      │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1      ┆ 30      ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2      ┆ 30      ┆ 60      ┆ 0       │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3      ┆ 30      ┆ 60      ┆ 70      │
└────────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

you can probably also stop after `implode()`, so you have list column instead of variable number of columns:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("price")
      .cumulative_eval(pl.element().implode())
      .over("date")
)

┌────────────┬────────┬──────────────┐
│ date       ┆ minute ┆ price        │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---          │
│ str        ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]    │
╞════════════╪════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1      ┆ [10]         │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2      ┆ [10, 20]     │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 1      ┆ [15]         │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2      ┆ [15, 10]     │
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 3      ┆ [15, 10, 20] │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 1      ┆ [30]         │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 2      ┆ [30, 60]     │
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3      ┆ [30, 60, 70] │
└────────────┴────────┴──────────────┘
```